# using VBA to refresh one by one the queries of my workbook - Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to refresh some queries from my workbook, for some reasons I get this error :

> The index does not belong to the selection (execution error 9)

I'm starting with using this :

```vb
    For Month=1 To 12 Step 1
      ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Tmp" & Month).OLEDBConnection.Refresh
    Next Month
```

I have 12 queries (`Tmp1 / Tmp2 / ...`) for 12 sheets (one for each month).

I already tried things like using :

**Not working**

```vb
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count 
    '(Result: QueryTables.Count = 0)
```

or :

```vb
    ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Tmp1").OLEDBConnection.Refresh
    '(Result: same error message)
```

**Working**

```vb
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    '(all my queries are refreshed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an index instead of the connection name.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.connections

You can get the connection name with the "name" property.

So, something like that should be ok :

```
For i=0 To NbConnections-1
  If ThisWorkBook.Connections(i).Name = "Query - Tmp" & Month Then
      ThisWorkbook.Connections(i).OLEDBConnection.Refresh
  End If
Next  i
```

Comment: Very helpfull, I will try it and make some tests tomorrow. Thanks